# Get effect of gradient stops in ie9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-9

I can't get the aforementioned effect.. 
I need the gradient to stop abruptly in the middle. In Ie9 it's all smooth - and shiny  ;/
I've generated my gradient here:http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/JRUnr/44/

Adding:

```
<!--[if gte IE 9]>
<style type="text/css">
.gradient {
filter: none;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

doesn't make any difference:( any help appreciated!

Comment: I strongly recommend using [CSS3Pie](http://css3pie.com/) for doing CSS gradients in IE9 and earlier. The `filter` and SVG methods have some serious limitations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use filter for IE9. Try use svg

```
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
```

Filter work only with 2 points.

Comment: it doesn't work in my ie9 -I didn't update ie so I've got original one (ie9) - maybe that's why?)

Comment: Try use !important for disable filter in ie9. your selector can carry more weight in CSS. <style type="text/css">.gradient {filter: none !important;}</style>

Answer (score 1):

I personnaly recommand this generator for your gradients :

**[SVG Gradient Background Maker](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/svggradientbackgroundmaker/default.html)**

***CSS:***

```
background-image:url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
background-size:cover;
```

This won't work for IE8 and under, but it works for IE 9>, Chrome and Firefox.

`background-size:cover;` is a fix for firefox to not repeat the gradient.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/U5mmT/)**

Comment: it doesn't work in my ie9 -I didn't update ie so I've got original one  (ie9) - maybe that's why?)